# How to customize Spring Rest Controller errors with Jackson or malformed request

Tags: java, spring-mvc

With a Spring @RestController, using Jackson to parse Json in request bodies, Spring will automatically detect an error in the json and returns a 500 response without the request ever reaching your controller.

Example

```
   public class SomeRequestDetails {
       String name;

       public String getName() {}
       public void setName(String n) {}
   }
   ....

   @RequestMapping(value = "/myEndPoint", method = RequestMethod.POST,
                   produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<SomeResponseObject> someRequest(@RequestBody SomeRequestDetails details) throws Exception {
  ....
```

Now if the json being posted is mis-shaped, for example

```
{
   "wrongField" : "Joe"
}
```

Spring will automatically return a 500 response to the client and will log a stack trace explaining the problem.  Maybe a string like *Missing required field 'name'* appears in the server logs.

**My question is**, is there a way I can intercept this error detected by spring and have some influence over the response that is returned to the client?

I'm okay with the server returning 500 (a 422 might be more accurate), but it would be nice to also include something like

```
{
   "error" : "Missing require field 'name'"
}
```

As the response body so that the client developers will have some information as to why their request failed.

By default the client gets a 500 with no body and my server logs the error.  This means client developers have to contact me to obtain information as to why their request is failing.  So I just want some control of the error mechanism so I can help with context for the client developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implementation of [JSR-303](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) like [hibernate-validator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator) to do this. In a nutshell, what we need to do is annotating the entity with desired validation .eg `@NotNull`:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class SomeRequestDetails {
   @NotNull
   String name;
   public String getName() {}
   public void setName(String n) {}
}
```

and use `@Valid` annotation for the corresponding argument:

```java
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RequestMapping(value = "/myEndPoint", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<SomeResponseObject> someRequest(@Valid @RequestBody SomeRequestDetails details) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, you will get `HTTP 400` in case of missing field. If you want to update the status code as well, you may want to a custom `@ExceptionHandler` for `MethodArgumentNotValidException` that repackages the error message within `ResponseEntity` with desired `HttpStatus` as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749580/spring-validator-custom-http-status).

References:

- [spring-webmvc + hibernate-validator](https://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator)
- [@Valid + @RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1569)

Comment: I don't see how this will return to developers the json error.  A mis-shaped json block is already detected, it just isn't communicated back via the HTTP response to developers.  The request never reaches the controller.